# Make selected by value

Tags: javascript

```
<select id="selectBox">
  <option value="2"> two </option>
  <option value="4"> four</option>
  <option value="6"> six </option>
</select>
```

I have value 4, Now how to make `selectBox` selected with value 4 with javascript?

Comment: I am not sure. Do you want to select the option value with 4 or want to change also the option text? Cause if you want just to be selected then its pretty easy and answer is below

Comment: I am trying to to change text as `selected` but now @curt solution also work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("selectBox").value=4;​
```

---

[**-- View Demo --**](http://jsfiddle.net/gptTP/)

Answer (score 1):

you can also do like this

```
 <option value="4" selected="selected"> four</option>
```

by default it get selected vale 4

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
function fnc(myid,other1,other2)
{
    document.getElementById(myid).text=myid+" is selected";
    document.getElementById(other1).text=other1;
    document.getElementById(other2).text=other2;
}
</script>
<select id="selectBox">
  <option value="2" id="two" onclick="fnc(this.id,'four','six')"> two </option>
  <option value="4" id="four" onclick="fnc(this.id,'two','six')"> four</option>
  <option value="6" id="six" onclick="fnc(this.id,'two','four')"> six </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not like that. Just like this output `<option value="4" selected> four</option>`. I've make mistake on the former comment. I should write option attribute instead of option text.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery ,you can do coding while javascript worrks. First you have to ***pick***
`<option value="4"> four</option>` that is: `$("#selectBox option[value='4']")`    then  you have to change  selected to true. Here is the code  :

`$("#selectBox option[value='4']").attr('selected', true);`